# Boot Failure from DVD

Tags: boot

I burned the latest ISO version of Ubuntu to a DVD (per the instructions on the site) and when I insert the disk and begin boot, all I get is Boot failure. The Bios has been set to boot from CD/DVD first, then my HD.

I was running WinXP and switched out the HD for a Solid State Drive.

Not sure what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can provide more information to solve the problem, like:

- What program are you using for burn the DVD ?
- Did you check if you really burn from ISO file or just burn the .iso into Dvd ?
- As @levlaz said, try to make a LiveUSB (in Windows, [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) )

When burning Dvds to try distros, i always do with the lowest speed, always close the disco (prevent futher record) and use "smart decision" (make the program choose the type of burning method). Always work for me.

- If you have another computer with Linux, try LiveUsb from UnetBooting app (Software Center on Ubuntu) or Brasero (pre-installed app)
- When booting with LiveUSB make sure to select "USB HDD" to boot first.

PS: switching HD to SSD will not cause any problem or trouble in both windows or linux distros. SSD is really like a HD to the motherboard, just with much more read/write speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try burn the ISO again at a lower speed? Sometimes data can get corrupted when burning an iso.

Also, have you tried booting from a USB, this is very simple and the biggest benefit is that you will be able to reuse the USB drive after you are finished for whatever you like.